# Any known implementation of Monero MPC mutlisigs?

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures, transaction-confirmation, multisig

I am looking for a whitepaper/science doc/source code that explains/implements MPC multisig for Monero.

Would appreciate any piece of inforamtion